# Can I put an image in a <td> tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<td colspan="23"><img src="images/layout_15.gif" width="887" height="115"></td>
```

But I was wondering if that can be changed to something like:

```
<td colspan="23" class="something">
```

or:

```
<td colspan="23" id="something">
```

and then can I define a style for the image in a CSS file? If so, how, and is it better doing it that way?

Comment: Why are you using tables for layout?

Comment: if you use them right tables are great for layout. why don't you like tables??

Comment: Tables are perfectly valid markup if you're displaying _tabular_ data.

Comment: @andrewk 1. table layouts are not nearly as flexible as CSS layouts, 2. using tables for design adds presentation logic to your markup (presentation and content should be separated), 3. nested tables are hell, 4. tables makes it harder for search engines to index your pages, 5. tables can't be rendered until the table and all its children have been parsed, 6. tables are intended for tabular data... Do I need to go on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn’t replace the `width` and `height` attributes of an `<img>` tag with CSS ones. Bitmap image files have an inherent pixel width and height, and that information is useful to the browser (for page layout) before the CSS file is downloaded and parsed.

Having re-read your question though, maybe you’re trying to get rid of the `<img>` tag altogether? If so, if you’ve got this HTML:

```
<td colspan="23" class="something"></td>
```

You can get the image to show up in it like this:

```
.something {
    width: 887px;
    height: 115px;
    background: url(images/layout_15.gif) left top no-repeat;
}
```

Note that the image’s file path in CSS is relative to the CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

You require a [Descendant CSS Selector](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_descendant.htm) so that you can target the image elements in a particular class/id of `<td>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all images embedded in the td to have that same width and height, you can use:

```
.something img{
 width:887px;
 height:115px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

CSS:

```
.something img { border: 10px solid red; }
```

HTML:

```
<td class="something"><img src="images/layout_15.gif"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! It is much better. Just ensure that you aren't sill using them to do layouts. Tables should only be used for tabular data.

if your html is:

```
<td class="first"></td>
```

Then your CSS can be

```
.first {
background: #ccc;
border: 1px solid #999;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

For example, of course.